# can't connect to svnserver remotely

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, server, connection

So, I'm trying to setup a source code repository on a centOS linux server machine so that I can access the files remotely over the internet. I've installed subversion, created the repository, setup the repo's svnserve.conf and passwd files properly, afaik. Then I started svnserver with the command "`svnserve -d -r [/path/to/repositories]`". I've also port forwarded port 3690 on the router that the server is connected with.

*Here's the issue.*
I can't seem to connect to the server remotely, but I can connect locally using:
 `svn checkout svn://127.0.0.1/[repo]`. 
Everything seems to work fine locally, on the machine itself, but remotely, I get:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://[server.ip.addr.ess]/[repo]'
svn: E000060: Can't connect to host '[server.ip.addr.ess]': Operation timed out
```

I can also successfully connect remotely with svn+ssh, when I turn the svnserver off, but I don't want to use svn+ssh.
What am I not doing right here?

Comment: Try connect to name instead of ip. Also check firewall and selinux on client side.

Comment: it doesn't have a name, the ip should work just fine, as I can ssh into it, I'll check the selinux

Comment: the selinux is completely disabled. It's a no go

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I figured that this  would be a programming/development question, since it is for a piece of software that is standard use in software development/programming, and that is what I'm using it for. Makes sense to me to have all the topics and things that a programmer might want to know all in the same place. That's why I posted it here. Also,note that the "What topics can I ask about here" Says, "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: I don't think Super User nor Unix & Linux Stack Exchange would fit the bill of this question, since this is not something that a power user might be using much, and the Subversion tool is not specific to Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue in this specific situation was that I needed to allow the connection to svnserve through the firewall, with iptables.

The command that I ran was `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT`

That command will allow all connections to port 3690, which is the default for svnserve, from any ip address using the tcp connection protocol. Note also, that you will need to make sure that the OUTPUT is open in iptables as well.

[Here](https://www.booleanworld.com/depth-guide-iptables-linux-firewall/) is a good article about iptables.